# ScrollMagic : JQuery element is not working for triggerElement

Tags: jquery, gsap, scrollmagic

As the documentation

> The value for `triggerElement` will be a **selector, DOM object or jQuery
>   Object** that defines the start of the scene. If undefined the scene
>   will start right at the start of the page (unless an offset is set).

But I think this is not OK for my case.

My HTML looks like

```
....
<section>
    <div class="scrollMagic">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
    et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.        
    </div>
    <div class="scrollMagic">
        <img src="abc1.jpg" width="100px" >
    </div>
</section>
<section>
    <div class="scrollMagic">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
    et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.        
    </div>
    <div class="scrollMagic">
        <img src="abc2.jpg" width="100px" >
    </div>
</section>
<section>
    <div class="scrollMagic">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
    et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.        
    </div>
    <div class="scrollMagic">
        <img src="abc3.jpg" width="100px" >
    </div>
</section>
....
```

I'd like to animate when user was scroll into repective section. Below is my JS code snippet.

```
  var scrollMagicController = new ScrollMagic.Controller({
    globalSceneOptions: {
      duration: 100
    }
  });

  $("section").each(function(index, elem) {
    var tween = TweenMax.to(elem, 1, {
      ease: SlowMo.ease.config(0.7, 0.7, false),
      opacity: 1,
      repeat: 1
    });

    var childElems = $(elem).find(".magicScroll");
    var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
      duration: 200,
      triggerElement: childElems,
    // offset: -500
    }).setTween(tween).addTo(scrollMagicController);
  });
```

I always get the error in my firefox developer console

```
12:11:02:444 (ScrollMagic.Scene) -> ERROR: Element defined in option "triggerElement" was not found:
```

How should I figure it out to work fine ?

Comment: I think I should itrate `childElems` also.

Answer (score 0):

I should iterate `childElems` also. Below is my working code for later reference.

```
  $("section").each(function(index, elem) {
    $(elem).addClass("animate-container" + index);
    var tween = TweenMax.to(".animate-container" + index, 1, {
      ease: Back.easeInOut.config(1.7),
      opacity: 1,
    });

    var childElems = $(elem).find(".magicScroll");
    $(childElems).each(function(innerIndex, childElem) {
      $(childElem).addClass("animate" + innerIndex);
      var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        tweenChanges: true,
        triggerElement: ".animate-container" + index + " .animate" + innerIndex,
        offset: -300,
        reverse: false,
      }).setTween(tween).addTo(scrollMagicController);
    });

  });
```